# How to unbundle JS bundle file

Tags: javascript, bundle

I have a xyz.js.bundle file. When I open it in a text editor, an XML file with all the JS scripts included comes in it with bundleHead.js and a bundleTail.js

I want to unbundle this js file in windows or linux. Please help me in un bundling it.

Answer (score 0):

there is one way where you convert it first to coffee script and re-convert that converted coffee script to javascript. Check  this [out](http://js2coffee.org/). Unfortunately this free version converter will give you a lot of variable of which you have to take long time to figure out the whole idea of the js file.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally wrote a PHP script which goes through all the files mentioned in the bundle and then appends the contents of those files in a new JS file.